# how could i use compareTo to iterate on userinput

Tags: java, compareto

Given an integer array of size N. For each element in the array, check whether there exist a smaller element on the next immediate position of the array.

If such an element exists, print that element. If there is no smaller element on the immediate next to the element then print -1.

I want to do this using `compareTo()`

```
import java.util.*;
class GodPlz
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            al.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(al);
        Iterator itr=al.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
          Integer I=(Intger)itr.next();
```

---

how should i proceed this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please include your own effort in the question. And why `compareTo()`?

Comment: import java.util.*;
class GodPlz
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("enter the number");
  while(sc.hasNext())
  {
   al.add(sc.nextInt());
  }
  System.out.println(al);
  Iterator itr=al.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext())
  {
   boolean b=(itr.compareTo(itr.next()));
   
    if(b<0)
     System.out.println(itr.next());
    else
     System.out.println("-1");
               }
 }
} ...i know this is incorrect.i dont know how to proceed this.

Comment: Update your question with that code instead of posting it as a comment